# How to create and fill an Unlimited Array

Tags: java, c#, arrays

Earlier last week I was in an android/Java class, and our lecturer likes to throw little challenges at us every now and then, just as fun little programs for us to think about.

The topic I'm studying is OOP and OOD in c# and Java environments, so this really doesn't have any huge leverage on my actual final project, and I'd like to stress this was an optional task set for fun.

The Task was asking for the programmer to:

> Create a program that could hold an **"unlimited"** array of integers (based on how many the user required) and find the max value in the array.

The issue wasn't the max method (easy), or the variables in the array (basic), but the array itself. we weren't allowed to use linked lists, it had to be an "Unlimited" 1D array that could take user input.

I've been playing around with the array for a while now, was going to make a circular array at first but that still doesn't solve many of the issues, and I can't really work out how to solve the problem in a way that this could be *ported over and used in c#*

any ideas as to how this could be achieved?

Comment: In Java, there's a class that do this and it's called `ArrayList`. In C#, I guess this is covered by `List` class.

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` in Java or `List<T>` in C#, that is like a dynamic length array. But I guess your teacher is probably looking for an implementation of dynamic array using regular arrays. Create an array and then `Re-Size`\increase  it with the input, something like `List<T>` does internally.

Comment: Or you can go with good old `(cons x y)` by using `Enumerable.Concat` between current array and new item: `unlimitedList = unlimitedList.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(newItem, 1))` (not exactly array, but `IEnumerable` is more generic unless you need indexing)

Comment: first buy an inifinite-Gb USB memory stick... actualy i think this problem is more about the highest number finding rather than the unlimitedness. sounds similar to 'remove duplicates from the phonebook' style problems

Comment: Interesting guys, going to try out ArrayList, I remember using it before but I forgot about it, my mind is filled with abstraction, ToString and inheritance right now. I'll get back to you guys when I've written the code, thanks!

Comment: If you *really* need to have an array and can't use a List/ArrayList, you can create a method that returns a new array with an additional index every time an item is added. It can be convoluted though, and is far from the best practice when Collection<E> (Java) and ICollection<T> (C#) already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use only `LinkedList` you can use any other implementation of `java.util.List`.

If you can't use at all `java.util.List` you can use an array with enough values as you need and use a pointer to the last value.
Something like this

```
 public class MyArray {
     private int[] myArray = new int[10000];
     private int index = -1;

     public void add(int obj) {
        index++;
        myArray[index] = obj;
     }

     public Integer removeLast() {
         if (index >= 0) {
             return myArray[index--];
         }
         return null;
     }

     public Integer get(int i) {
         if (i >= 0 && i < index) {
             return myArray[i];
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Note. This is very similar to the internal representation of `ArrayList`. Take a tour of source of `ArrayList` to know more, the biggest difference is that this implentation is blocked to a maximum of 10000 ints, instead the `ArrayList` can grows if necessary, but I think that the grows implementation is outside the scope of your exercise.